# Energy changed by displacement of lattice

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body, quantum-statistics

In the famous textbook *Introduction to Many-Body Physics* by Piers Coleman，In Chap 8.7, *Interacting electrons and phonons, on page 270*, the author says

> Let $\vec{\Phi}(x)$ be dispacement of the lattice at a given point $x$, so that the strain tensor in the lattice is given by
> $$u_{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{2}(\nabla_{\mu}\Phi_{\nu}(x)+\nabla_{\nu}\Phi_{\mu}(x))$$
> In general, we expect a small change in the strain to modify the background potential of the lattice, modifying the energies of the elecrons so that, locally
> $$\epsilon(k)=\epsilon_{0}(k)+C_{\mu\nu}u_{\mu\nu}(x)$$

I cannot understant, why the corrections to energies of electrons are combinations of elements of strain tensor. Why wouldn't we expect it to be like
$$\epsilon(k)=\epsilon_{0}(k)+C_{\mu}\Phi_{\mu}(x)$$
or
$$\epsilon(k)=\epsilon_{0}(k)+C_{\mu\nu}\Phi_{\mu}(x)\Phi_{\nu}(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd equation of yours is nonlinear in displacement, so it could describe higher-order effects. If we're up to building up a (sort of) perturbation theory, and think of energy in terms of $\varepsilon_0+\Delta\varepsilon$, we should consider linearized equations and lowest-order terms first. At small displacements (where the perturbation theory is applicable), the term proportional to $\Phi^2$ will be much smaller than that proportional to $\Phi$ and thus can be neglected.

The 1st one is linear, but it has another problem. Consider homogeneous displacement across the entire solid, so $\Phi(x)=\rm{const}$. This corresponds to the "movement" of the entire solid; obviously electrons' energy will not change due to the translational symmetry, as their wavefunctions will simply adjust to the new positions of the nuclei. Yet, in your formula it will correspond to the energy change $\Delta\varepsilon$. To avoid this contradiction, you should associate $\Delta\varepsilon$ with inhomogeneous displacement which cannot be described in this way. And this is where strain $u$ comes about, because the degree of inhomogeneity is proportional to $\nabla\Phi$ (again, in the linear limit).